# Match node in JSON input

Tags: xslt

I have the following code, which I am using to transform a JSON file to another JSON.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:fcn="http://www.re.com/2018/local-functions" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn fcn exsl" version="3.0">
       <xsl:param as="xs:string" name="json">[{
            "results": [
                {
                    "id": "5b33c2e8-8ab2-4314-82bf-e41a007c076f",
                    "profileId": "0f53bfe5-4ef3-4424-9ad2-ad8181007e22"
                }
            ],
            "_embedded": {
            },
            "paging": {
                "pageNumber": 1,
                "pageSize": 10,
                "totalCount": 4
            }
        }]</xsl:param>
       <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text" />
       <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
          <xsl:variable name="input-as-xml" select="json-to-xml($json)" />
          <xsl:variable name="transformed-xml">
             <array xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                <xsl:for-each select="fn:array[@key = 'results']/*">
                   <map>
                      <xsl:if test="*[@key = 'id'] != ''">
                         <string key="id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="fn:string[@key = 'id']" />
                         </string>
                      </xsl:if>
                   </map>
                </xsl:for-each>
             </array>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($transformed-xml, map {'indent': true()})" />
       </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to match the results object, but when I apply the stylesheet, I am getting an empty JSON output.

Some help with matching the results object correctly would be appreciated.

The input-as-xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<array xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <map>
      <array key="results">
         <map>
            <string key="id">5b33c2e8-8ab2-4314-82bf-e41a007c076f</string>
            <string key="profileId">0f53bfe5-4ef3-4424-9ad2-ad8181007e22</string>
         </map>
      </array>
      <map key="_embedded"/>
      <map key="paging">
         <number key="pageNumber">1</number>
         <number key="pageSize">10</number>
         <number key="totalCount">4</number>
      </map>
   </map>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, I think the `xsl:for-each` should be something like `<xsl:for-each select="$input-as-xml/fn:array[@key = 'results']/*">`, so you're selecting within the right context.

But I don't think that's quite enough: The XML that comes from the conversion will contain an `<fn:array>` whose first child will be an `<fn:map>` which will have an entry of the form `<fn:array key="results">`, so you need to select deeper into the structure.

It's probably a good idea to print out the value of `$input-as-xml` (in indented form) for ease of diagnostics.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question with the value of $inpit-as-xml. Is this what you wanted to see?

Comment: Presumably you now know how to change your XPath to select the right fn:array element.

Comment: To be honest I am stuck with selecting the right element. I tried what you suggested but I get: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value of variable $json ("{ "results": [ {...", "notes")

Comment: That doesn't look like the variable `$json` that appears in the original code. I don't know what your code now looks like so it's hard to help with the debugging; it's probably best to open a new question at this point.